# HTML Form submission with GET and extra arguments

Tags: python, html, django, forms, submission

Here is my situation, I have a page with a form on it. The form is just a query, so I'm using the "GET" method. I have a variable which I am passing around as a token, the variable is of the form "x=2&y=5" since the variable is passed into my page as an encoded url it is just extra work to parse it out to a dictionary of {'x':2,'y':5}. What would be ideal is something like the following:

```
<form method="GET" action="/path/to/action/?x=2&y=5">
    <input type="text" name="some_other_val">
    ... more inputs here etc.
</form>
```

Unfortunately when I do it this way the browser erases the ending x=2&y=5 and just appends the form fields as the arguments. The reason that I don't just use `<input type="hidden" name="x" value="2">` is because like I said the string is already in that form, and I would need to specifically decode it. Adding the value to the end of the action url is simpler. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please note I found a very similar thread about this here [adding URL parameters to a form PHP HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724817/adding-url-parameters-to-a-form-php-html) but none of the solutions presented solve my basic problem. I also tried the tip of appending an '&' on the end but it did not work either! Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: we might be able to suggest a function to help you do the required URL parsing if you let us know what language you're using to render the page.

Comment: I'm using python django 1.3 on python 2.7.

Comment: check out the parse_qs function in the urlparse module: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

Answer (score 4):

You *should* use hidden form elements for the extra parameters as you have described:

```
<input type="hidden" id="x" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" id="y" value="5" />
```

This ensures that the parameters will appear correctly on the URL when using `GET` instead of getting removed.

I don't quite get your argument against them, as if you can append them to the form action you should be able to simply change that to `hidden` form elements easily enough.

Comment: It did NOT work for me (Django 1.8). I had to use `name`, not `id` to make it work: `<input type="hidden" name="x" value="2" />`