# how to add a parameter to the url in php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add the parameter cs with a value of 1 to the url using a form and hidden type input.  When I execute this, I have a simple if statement that checks to see if $_GET['cs'] is = to 1, but I get a Notice: Undefined index.  I'm a php beginner, any help, explanations, or alternatives is very much appreciated.

```
        echo '<form>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="cs" value="1">';
        echo '</form>';
    
        if($_GET['cs'] == 1) {
            echo'working';  
        }
        else {
            echo 'not working';
        }
```

Comment: Does the parameter show up in the url after submitting? How do you submit?

Comment: How do you submit the form? You will get value of $_GET['cs'] only after the form is submitted, use `if(isset($_GET['cs']))` to check if the parameter was sent. Also add `method="get"` attribute on form. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724817/adding-url-parameters-to-a-form-php-html/5724938) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only after form is submitted you will see 'cs' in $_GET array.
The $_GET array contains all parameters on the URL line.
For example if a URL is: https://example.com?param1=1&param2=2
You will get a $_GET array with two entries ('param1' and 'param2') with values 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a check using the isset function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Otherwise it will try to access the parameter if it isn't sent. In your case the parameter was probably not sent.

Answer (score 0):

- Url in html:

```
<a href="get_varaible.php?varaible=<?php echo $value ?>">test the get method</a>
```

- The url test

```
<?php 

if ($_GET['varaible'] == true) {
    $varaible = 'Its work';
    $value = false;
}else{
    $varaible = 'Oooppss';
    $value = true;
}
    echo $varaible . '<br>';
?>
```

- Full code:

```
<?php 

if ($_GET['varaible'] == true) {
    $varaible = 'Its work';
    $value = false;
}else{
    $varaible = 'Oooppss';
    $value = true;
}
    echo $varaible . '<br>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>get varaible</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="get_varaible.php?varaible=<?php echo $value ?>">test the get method</a>
</body>
</html>
```